# ova fails to import, seems related to the BootOrderSection tag in the ovf

Tags: vsphere, vcenter

I've got an ova file that I've created with packer (via [this](https://github.com/jetbrains-infra/packer-builder-vsphere) plugin) that imports fine into my local vCenter managed vSphere cluster. I'm on version 6.5. I've got reports that a customer was unable to import this ova into their similar cluster. I don't have any information about what version they're running. Locally, I was able to reproduce their error on an unrelated vSphere 6.5 instance that isn't under vCenter management.

When I try to import the ova, when I'm at the end ready to let it upload the ova, I get the following message:

[screenshot of error in vSphere web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JwNR.png)

If I continue anyway, the "upload" completes immediately and produces a VM that takes up no space and won't boot. After 5 minutes of thinking, vSphere seems to decide that it's broken and automatically deletes it.

Interestingly, I tracked it down to the following bit of xml in the ovf file inside the ova:

```
<vmw:BootOrderSection vmw:instanceId="8" vmw:type="disk">
    <Info>Virtual hardware device boot order</Info>
</vmw:BootOrderSection>
```

If I remove this, update the sha256 value in the manifest file, and re-tar the ova file, that one works fine on both of my environments.

I've attached the entire ovf file from my ova for reference, including what I believe to be the offending BootOrderSection tag.

Any one have any idea what's wrong with my standalone vSphere environment, or my customer's vCenter cluster that isn't showing up on my local vCenter cluster?

The entire ovf that fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by VMware VirtualCenter Server, User: PD\jprice, UTC time: 2018-10-11T13:58:30.867527Z-->
<Envelope vmw:buildId="build-5973321" xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:cim="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/common" xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData" xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf" xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <References>
    <File ovf:href="safeconnect-disk1.vmdk" ovf:id="file1" ovf:size="3689997824"/>
  </References>
  <DiskSection>
    <Info>Virtual disk information</Info>
    <Disk ovf:capacity="300" ovf:capacityAllocationUnits="byte * 2^30" ovf:diskId="vmdisk1" ovf:fileRef="file1" ovf:format="http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized" ovf:populatedSize="6508576768"/>
  </DiskSection>
  <NetworkSection>
    <Info>The list of logical networks</Info>
    <Network ovf:name="Services">
      <Description>The Services network</Description>
    </Network>
  </NetworkSection>
  <VirtualSystem ovf:id="safeconnect-6.5-ova">
    <Info>A virtual machine</Info>
    <Name>safeconnect-6.5-ova</Name>
    <OperatingSystemSection ovf:id="101" vmw:osType="otherLinux64Guest">
      <Info>The kind of installed guest operating system</Info>
      <Description>Other Linux (64-bit)</Description>
    </OperatingSystemSection>
    <VirtualHardwareSection>
      <Info>Virtual hardware requirements</Info>
      <System>
        <vssd:ElementName>Virtual Hardware Family</vssd:ElementName>
        <vssd:InstanceID>0</vssd:InstanceID>
        <vssd:VirtualSystemIdentifier>safeconnect-6.5-ova</vssd:VirtualSystemIdentifier>
        <vssd:VirtualSystemType>vmx-10</vssd:VirtualSystemType>
      </System>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AllocationUnits>hertz * 10^6</rasd:AllocationUnits>
        <rasd:Description>Number of Virtual CPUs</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>8 virtual CPU(s)</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>1</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:Limit>0</rasd:Limit>
        <rasd:ResourceType>3</rasd:ResourceType>
        <rasd:VirtualQuantity>8</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AllocationUnits>byte * 2^20</rasd:AllocationUnits>
        <rasd:Description>Memory Size</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>16384MB of memory</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>2</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:Reservation>16384</rasd:Reservation>
        <rasd:ResourceType>4</rasd:ResourceType>
        <rasd:VirtualQuantity>16384</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Address>0</rasd:Address>
        <rasd:Description>SCSI Controller</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>SCSI controller 0</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>3</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>lsilogic</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>6</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="slotInfo.pciSlotNumber" vmw:value="16"/>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Address>1</rasd:Address>
        <rasd:Description>IDE Controller</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>IDE 1</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>4</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceType>5</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Address>0</rasd:Address>
        <rasd:Description>IDE Controller</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>IDE 0</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>5</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceType>5</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item ovf:required="false">
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:ElementName>Video card</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>6</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceType>24</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="enable3DSupport" vmw:value="false"/>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="use3dRenderer" vmw:value="automatic"/>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="useAutoDetect" vmw:value="false"/>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="videoRamSizeInKB" vmw:value="4096"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ovf:required="false">
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:ElementName>VMCI device</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>7</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>vmware.vmci</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>1</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="allowUnrestrictedCommunication" vmw:value="false"/>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="slotInfo.pciSlotNumber" vmw:value="33"/>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AddressOnParent>0</rasd:AddressOnParent>
        <rasd:ElementName>Hard disk 1</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:HostResource>ovf:/disk/vmdisk1</rasd:HostResource>
        <rasd:InstanceID>8</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:Parent>3</rasd:Parent>
        <rasd:ResourceType>17</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="backing.writeThrough" vmw:value="false"/>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AddressOnParent>7</rasd:AddressOnParent>
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>true</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Connection>Services</rasd:Connection>
        <rasd:Description>E1000 ethernet adapter on &quot;Services&quot;</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>Network adapter 1</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>9</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>E1000</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="slotInfo.pciSlotNumber" vmw:value="32"/>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="wakeOnLanEnabled" vmw:value="true"/>
      </Item>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="cpuHotAddEnabled" vmw:value="false"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="cpuHotRemoveEnabled" vmw:value="false"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="firmware" vmw:value="bios"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="virtualICH7MPresent" vmw:value="false"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="virtualSMCPresent" vmw:value="false"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="memoryHotAddEnabled" vmw:value="false"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="nestedHVEnabled" vmw:value="false"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="powerOpInfo.powerOffType" vmw:value="soft"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="powerOpInfo.resetType" vmw:value="soft"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="powerOpInfo.standbyAction" vmw:value="checkpoint"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="powerOpInfo.suspendType" vmw:value="hard"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.afterPowerOn" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.afterResume" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.beforeGuestShutdown" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.beforeGuestStandby" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.syncTimeWithHost" vmw:value="false"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.toolsUpgradePolicy" vmw:value="manual"/>
      <vmw:ExtraConfig ovf:required="false" vmw:key="nvram" vmw:value="safeconnect-6.5-ova.nvram"/>
    </VirtualHardwareSection>
    <vmw:BootOrderSection vmw:instanceId="8" vmw:type="disk">
      <Info>Virtual hardware device boot order</Info>
    </vmw:BootOrderSection>
  </VirtualSystem>
</Envelope>
```